# swipe to delete when already in edit mode

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have an iphone app using a uitableview where I'd like the "reorder" controls to always be displayed, and have the user swipe to delete rows.

The approach I'm currently taking is to put the tableview in edit mode and allow selection in edit mode

```
self.tableView.editing = YES;
self.tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
```

I then hide the red delete circles using

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return NO;
}
```

I cant figure out how to get the swipe gesture to bring up the "delete" on the right side when the tableview is already in edit mode, can somebody point me in the right direction?

alternatively, if someone knows how to get the cell reordering controls to show when NOT in edit mode, that would also be a workable solution

cheers

Comment: Just thought I'd add that I've done a *lot* of research into this issue (I have exactly the same requirement) and I don't believe it's possible without implementing your own swipe logic. I also don't believe it's possible to show re-order controls in non-edit mode without similarly duplicating much of Apple's logic.

Comment: Have you done this ?

Answer (score 1):

When the user swipes on a given row, you need to store a reference somewhere so that you can change the value returned by `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` and `shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath`.  Your best bet is likely to use `indexPathForCell` on the cell that is swiped and store that.  Then in the two display methods above you need to check if the `NSIndexPath` is the same or not (I'm not sure if they will be the same pointer or if you'll need to compare the section/row values - testing required).  If they match, display the delete button.

Note that you may need to call `reloadData` on your tableView to have the effect appear without scrolling away and back again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if the way you're headed now would break the Human Interface guidelines, which would result in the app not getting approved.

I can't see why you can't capture the swipe gesture and then use that to 'unhide' the red delete (stop sign) icons for the delete confirmation?