# Swipe to Delete for a table already in edit mode

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a tableview that loads with isEditing = YES.  This is a bit of a hack (but a reasonable one I think) because I want one of my cells to always display the 'add' icon.  I don't want the other cells to include the 'delete' icon so I am returning UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone for these.

However, I would still like to provide swipe to delete functionality on those cells.  Since the tableview is already in edit mode, is this going to be possible?

If not, I will probably achieve the 'add' icon using the cells imageView, but this seems hacky too.

Edit: Similar question found here:
[swipe to delete when already in edit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371185/swipe-to-delete-when-already-in-edit-mode)

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I am looking for something similar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [swipe to delete when already in edit mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371185/swipe-to-delete-when-already-in-edit-mode)

Answer (score -2):

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return YES;
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
       [myArray removeObjectFromindex];
      }
    [mytableview reloadData];
}
```

Comment: This does not actually answer the question. It does not enable swipe-to-delete when the table is in edit mode.